# css animation , just want to use setInterval to make the animation work many times ,but it only work once

Tags: jquery, css, animation

there are two wheels,one rolls left ,one rolls right,I want to use jquery to make the wheels roll one by each other and loop, I could write one wheel in jquery,but I don't know how to write them in a jquery animation queue.

html:

```
<div id="wheel1">
    <p>Running left</p>
</div>
<div id = "wheel2">
    <p>Running right</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wheel1{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        float: right;
        /*animation: myrotate2 3s ease-out forwards;*/
    }
    .roll-left{
        animation: roll-left 2s ease-out forwards;
    }
    @keyframes roll-left{
     0% {}
     50% {transform: translate(-1000px) rotate(-720deg)}
     100% {}
    }
    #wheel2{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        /*animation: myrotate1 3s ease forwards;*/

    }
    .roll-right{
        animation: roll-right 2s ease forwards;
    }
    @keyframes roll-right{
      0% {}
     50% {transform: translate(1000px) rotate(720deg)}
     100% {}
    }

    p{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        margin: 30px;
    }
```

jquery:

```
setInterval(function(){
        $("#wheel1").addClass('roll-left').one('animationed',function(){
            $("#wheel1").removeClass('roll-left');
        });
    },2000);
```

Comment: you mean animatione**n**d

Comment: see madalin ivascu answer its working. I update your fiddle check here https://jsfiddle.net/uaxsbpnk/

Comment: You've misspelled the word _animationed_, should be _animationend_ with _end_ in the end, not _ed_

Comment: @LGSon Yeah, you are right. I fixed it and everything becomes well..Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

To loop your animation you should use `animation-iteration-count`

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

you need to tweak your animations

```css
#wheel1{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        float: right;
        /*animation: myrotate2 3s ease-out forwards;*/
    }
    .roll-left{
        animation: roll-left 2s ease-out forwards;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes roll-left{
     0% {}
     25% {transform: translate(-1000px) rotate(-720deg)}
     50% {transform: translate(0) rotate(0)}/*wait for the secon animation to start*/
    }
    #wheel2{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        /*animation: myrotate1 3s ease forwards;*/

    }
    .roll-right{
        animation: roll-right 2s ease forwards;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes roll-right{
     0%{}
     50% {transform: translate(0) rotate(0)}/*wait for the first animation to stop*/
     75% {transform: translate(1000px) rotate(720deg)}
     100% {}
    }

    p{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        margin: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wheel1" class="roll-left">
    <p>Running left</p>
</div>
<div id = "wheel2" class="roll-right">
    <p>Running right</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,I just want to make wheel1 rolls first ,after wheel1 stops, wheel2 start to roll

Comment: It also seems the setInterval function's time parameter “2000” doesn't work.I change 2000ms ->5000ms,but the interval didn't change

Comment: If I add "infinite" to css, then it would be roll forever but nothing to do with setInterval

Answer (score 1):

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

is correct try this in your css

```js
setInterval(function(){

        $("#wheel1").addClass('roll-left').one('animationed',function(){
            $("#wheel1").removeClass('roll-left');
        });
    },2000);
    
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#wheel2").addClass('roll-right').one('animationed',function(){
            $("#wheel2").removeClass('roll-right');
        });
    },2000);
```

```css
#wheel1{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        float: right;
        /*animation: myrotate2 3s ease-out forwards;*/
    }
    .roll-left{
        animation: roll-left 2s ease-out forwards;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes roll-left{
     0% {}
     50% {transform: translate(-1000px) rotate(-720deg)}
     100% {}
    }
    #wheel2{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: pink;
        border:5px dotted purple;
        border-radius: 80px;
        /*animation: myrotate1 3s ease forwards;*/

    }
    .roll-right{
        animation: roll-right 2s ease forwards;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes roll-right{
      0% {}
     50% {transform: translate(1000px) rotate(720deg)}
     100% {}
    }

    p{
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        margin: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wheel1">
    <p>Running left</p>
</div>
<div id = "wheel2">
    <p>Running right</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi,I just want to make wheel1 rolls first ,after wheel1 stops, wheel2 start to roll

Comment: It also seems the setInterval function's time parameter “2000” doesn't work.I change 2000ms ->5000ms,but the interval didn't change

Comment: If I add "infinite" to css, then it would be roll forever but nothing to do with setInterval